# Breeze many-to-many example needed

Tags: many-to-many, breeze

My join table/class looks like this:

```
public class OrganizationUser
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
}
```

When I save a new Organization and OrganizationUser entity in a single saveChanges() call, everything in the database is great, and Breeze seems to think everything succeeded.  (all Id's get set correctly, Id's are passed back to Javascript, and the promise resolves fine)

However, _hasChanges in my Breeze manager stays set to true, causing future saves to crash.  I stepped through the Breeze code and for some reason Breeze seems to think the OrganizationUser still needs to be updated.

Am I doing something wrong in my join table class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set a many-to-many relation. (i.e. Organization-OrgUser-User)

Note that Breeze does not support many-to-many unless it has a payload. By seeing the IsReadOnly property, I could tell it's a m-m with payload, but I'm not sure about having the FKs as PKs. 
I'd have a PK for the linking table aside from the FKs:

```
public class OrganizationUser {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
}
```

You might want to take a look at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties.

Comment: Thanks! I read somewhere that Breeze handled many-to-many by exposing the join table.  But adding the primary key got it to work.